# which event is used when change the one textbox value it should change the related value in another textbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, events, textbox, onchange

I want to change multiple **textbox value**, at that time the result should come on **result textbox value** on the **spot**.

I googled this question and most answered is that from **change** event this will work, but I try **change** as well as **on** event still didnt work for me.

Here is my view code

```
<nop-editor asp-for="Weight" />
<nop-editor asp-for="Quantity" />
<nop-editor asp-for="Fine" />
<nop-editor asp-for="Rate" />
<nop-editor asp-for="LabourCharge" /> 
<nop-editor asp-for="UnitPriceInclTax" />
```

Here is my jquery code,

```
$("#LabourCharge, #LabourChargeUnit, #Rate").on('input', function () { 
    var fine = $('input[id="Fine"]').val();
    var rate = $('input[id="Rate"]').val();
    totalFineRate = fine * rate;

    if (selectedLabourChargeUnitId == 1) {
        var weight = $('input[id="Weight"]').val();
        var labourCharge = $('input[id="LabourCharge"]').val();
        var totalLabourCharge = weight * labourCharge;
    }

    if (selectedLabourChargeUnitId == 2) {
            var pcs = $('input[id="Quantity"]').val();
            var labourCharge = $('input[id="LabourCharge"]').val();
        var totalLabourCharge = pcs * labourCharge;
    }

    totalPrice = totalLabourCharge + totalFineRate;
    $('#UnitPriceInclTax').val(totalPrice);
});
```

Now as per the code, when I change **totalLabourCharge** or **totalFineRate** then the related value should show the **$('#UnitPriceInclTax').val();** which is not working.

Comment: Could you show the actual HTML in the question so we can create a working example to debug

Comment: what is `selectedLabourChargeUnitId` here ? Also why not simply use `input` as selector ?